# Get audioSessionId of song running in background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, equalizer

In a Project.,when i `equalize` like

```
equalizer = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

`Equalizer` is working fine. but when i don't have `sessionId`. Is there any `global sessionId`(0 is according to me) . because when i initialize `equalizer(0,0).` it is not working. why?

I set `audioSessionId` to 0 because i don't have access to a song which is run by any other app. Or how could i get `audioSession` id of song.

**Or is there any other way to equalize a song run by another app.**